# Using JQZoom within a Fancybox iFrame without loading jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, parent-child, javascript, jqzoom

I'm using Fancybox in a page (call it parent.html) to load an iframe (call it child.html).  In the child.html page I'm using JQzoom.  I have everyhting set up and good to go, but I wonder if there's a way to reduce the load time (or will load time be minimal?).  Right now I load the JQuery library in both the parent and child pages, and then load the JQZoom library in the child page.

I will have several child pages, but only one parent from which the child pages are loaded using Fancybox.  Is there a way to use JQzoom in the child window without loading the JQuery library?  Even better would be to load everything, including all the functions and the JQzoom library, into the parent page, and then just access these functions/library files from the child page.

Right now the child page has the following code and script to trigger JQzoom:

```
...
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jqzoom/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js'></script>  
</head>
<body>
<a href="large.jpg" class="myID"><img src="small.jpg"></a>
...
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.myID').jqzoom({
      //... zqzoom OPTIONS  
    });  
  });
</script> 
...
```

I'm a designer, so if you do have any suggestions please treat me like the leotarded coder that I am :)

Thanks!

Comment: If it's the same file, from the same location, it will be cached. Load time will be minimal.

Comment: Hi ahren, so the first iframe window that's opened in Fancybox may take a bit longer, but the rest won't because the libraries are cached?

Comment: If the libraries are available in the parent window, they'll be cached from there (or possibly before, since you're using a CDN). So fancybox would only need to load the contents of child.html, and the JS files will come from the cache.